# INSERT in stored proc after Parsing a data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to ask for help on how to outright insert a parsed data which i parsed using select.

Here's my code guys

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ParsingProcedureR10V2]    Script Date: 11/12/2014 1:08:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParsingProcedureR10V2]
@ProductCode VARCHAR(500)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT [Account]  = LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX(',',@ProductCode) - 1),
   [date&time] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12),
   [Status] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 40, 1),
   [Lat] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 42, 10),
   [Long] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 53, 11),
   [Speed] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 65, 4),
       [HDOP] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 74, 3),
   [statcode] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 8),
   [ENGINE] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 1),
   [KM2] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 123,11);
```

Thank you for all those who will help me in advance and thanks for the site for letting me post.

Comment: What do you mean by outright insert.?

Comment: insert into tablename(col1,col2,..)select col_parsed1,col_parsed2..

Comment: do u have a table with columns Account, date&time, Status..etc.,

Comment: Yes Vera I do have a table ready with the columns same as the parsed data.

Comment: Try the answer I posted. Just added insert query along with select query.

Comment: Had you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  Replace the TABLENAME with your table name and run it.

```
USE [SMSGPS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ParsingProcedureR10V2]    Script Date: 11/12/2014 1:08:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParsingProcedureR10V2]
@ProductCode VARCHAR(500)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Account, date&time, Status, Lat, Long, Speed, HDOP,  
      statcode, ENGINE, KM2) 
SELECT [Account]  = LEFT(@ProductCode,CHARINDEX(',',@ProductCode) - 1),
   [date&time] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 27, 12),
   [Status] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 40, 1),
   [Lat] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 42, 10),
   [Long] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 53, 11),
   [Speed] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 65, 4),
   [HDOP] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 74, 3),
   [statcode] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 8),
   [ENGINE] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 78, 1),
   [KM2] = SUBSTRING(@ProductCode, 123,11);
```